# SQL Query to get time periods contained in another one in the same table

Tags: sql, date, intervals, range

I have the following table (person_program):

```
program_id   person_id   start_date   end_date    
1            15588499    01-01-2014   02-16-2014
2            15588499    02-17-2014   03-01-2014  
3            15588499    02-15-2014   02-21-2014
```

I need to get the program_id that are contained by another time period in the same table (in this case, program_id = 3).

Any idea to solve this?

Thanks!!

Comment: Contained by another time period in the same table, regardless of person_id, or contained by another time period in the same table where the person_id is the same?

Comment: Can you tell why #3?  ID#3 is within #1, but then #2 is within #3 and #3 has the highest end date and they are all listed as the same person (unless sample data was an oops by copy/paste)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can reference the same table and get overlapping periods:

```
select t1.program_id ThisOne, t2.program_id OverlapsWith
from person_program t1
inner join person_program t2
    on t1.program_id < t2.program_id
    and t1.person_id = t2.person_id
    and t2.start_date > t1.end_date
```

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4606d/3)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
select *
from person_program x
where exists (select 1 from person_program y where y.start_date <= x.start_date and y.person_id = x.person_id and y.program_id <> x.program_id)
  or exists (select 1 from person_program y where y.end_date >= x.end_date and y.person_id = x.person_id and y.program_id <> x.program_id)
```

Note: This finds situations where, for the same person_id, there is another record on the table, with a different program_id, having a start and end date FULLY contained within the range of another.

EDIT: I just change the AND to OR, as it looks like, from your post, you are looking for partial, not necessarily full, overlaps. This should do that.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are passing in the `program_id` you want to find overlaps for, and partial overlaps are OK:

```
DECLARE @program_id int = 3

SELECT PP.program_id,
    PP.person_id
FROM person_program PP
INNER JOIN person_program Source
    ON PP.start_date <= Source.end_date
    AND PP.end_date >= Source.start_date
    AND Source.program_id = @program_id
```